# How to run two application on tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi I am using STS and myeclipse tool. I want to run application together from both tools. I have changed the port number of tomcat server in both tools. But only one application is running, when I am trying to run other application it gives following error. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:590)
```

Comment: Just deploy them both on the same tomcat instance.

Comment: are you running 2 tomcat instances? please show your `server.xml` configuration

Comment: Yes I am trying to run application on 2 tomcat instances.

Comment: I am using tomcat7 in STS and myeclipse using inbuilt tomcat to run the application. In myeclipse there is no option to add tomcat7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Tomcat instances are trying to start on the same port (8005). Change the Connector port for one of those two instances.

```
<Connector port="8006" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```